# use bison to make executable file but error

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I followed the [Flex and Bison tutorial](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html) to learn flex & bison ,
but I'm stuck. When I compile with
"g++ snazzle.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -o snazzle",
I get these error messages:

```
 snazzle.tab.c: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
 snazzle.tab.c:1403: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
 snazzle.tab.c:1546: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
 /tmp/ccFyBCBm.o: In function `yyparse':
 snazzle.tab.c:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `yylex'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my env is ubuntu 10.04 
bison 2.4.1
flex 2.5.35

I still can not find the problem. first I compile with "bison -o snazzle.y", then it generate two snazzle.tab.c and snazzle.tab.h respectively. finally I compile with "g++ snazzle.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -o snazzle". my code as follew :

```
snazzle.l
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "snazzle.tab.h" 
%}
%%
[ \t]          ;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ { yylval.fval = atof(yytext); return FLOAT; }
[0-9]+         { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return INT; }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+   {
// we have to copy because we can't rely on yytext not changing underneath us:
yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);
return STRING;
}
.              ;
%%
```

---

```
snazzle.y
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" int yyparse();
extern "C" FILE *yyin;

void yyerror(char *s);
%}

%union {
int ival;
float fval;
char *sval;
}

%token <ival> INT
%token <fval> FLOAT
%token <sval> STRING

%%

snazzle:
INT snazzle      { cout << "bison found an int: " << $1 << endl; }
| FLOAT snazzle  { cout << "bison found a float: " << $1 << endl; }
| STRING snazzle { cout << "bison found a string: " << $1 << endl; }
| INT            { cout << "bison found an int: " << $1 << endl; }
| FLOAT          { cout << "bison found a float: " << $1 << endl; }
| STRING         { cout << "bison found a string: " << $1 << endl; }
;
%%

main() {
// open a file handle to a particular file:
FILE *myfile = fopen("a.snazzle.file", "r");
// make sure it is valid:
if (!myfile) {
    cout << "I can't open a.snazzle.file!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
// set flex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
yyin = myfile;

// parse through the input until there is no more:
do {
    yyparse();
} while (!feof(yyin));
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
cout << "EEK, parse error!  Message: " << s << endl;
// might as well halt now:
exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Unless you've done something odd like defining YY_DECL or used some extra args to flex, yylex should be defined in lex.yy.c. Best guess is that you haven't actually run flex, or that it failed and you have an old/empty lex.yy.c lying around that you're picking up by accident. Without more details (actual command lines to run bison/flex and actual contents of the .y and .l files), I doubt you'll get much help.

Comment: I still can not find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a bunch of things as `extern "C"` in one source file but not in the other -- either get rid of the `"C"` or copy those declarations into the .l file.  Its actually probably best to put all those declarations into a .h file that you #include everywhere.  This has nothing specific to do with flex/bison, just a general C/C++ issue.